# c++ segment fault at the end of execution

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

My code compiles and for the most part does what it is intended to but I get a segment fault at the end of execution and it is suppose to update (append) the file but does not

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>


size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
        size_t written;
        written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
        return written;
}



int main(void)
{
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;

        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=155");

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                        curl_easy_strerror(res));

        FILE * pFile;
        pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","a+");
        if (pFile!=NULL)
        {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, pFile);
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                fclose (pFile);
        }

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

here is the gdb debug output:

```
gdb /home/coinz/cryptsy/getprice.o /home/coinz/cryptsy/core
GNU gdb (Gentoo 7.8 vanilla) 7.8
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.gentoo.org/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /home/coinz/cryptsy/getprice.o...done.

warning: exec file is newer than core file.
[New LWP 665]

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./getprice.o'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000011e12a0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00000000011e12a0 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007f9e78b9ca48 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007f9e78bb4cd0 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007f9e78bb0a4a in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007f9e78bb8fe8 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007f9e78bb9e15 in curl_multi_perform () from /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007f9e78bb22d6 in curl_easy_perform () from /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x0000000000400a76 in main () at getprice.cpp:35
        pFile = 0x11e12a0
        curl = 0x11ce2c0
        res = CURLE_OK
(gdb)
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code in a debugger to see where it actually stops?

Comment: Then it probably has problems loading pFile seeing as I don't see a path defined, only a name string.

Comment: the program fetches the webpage, outputs everything to the buffer but the last characters are 'segment fault' and the file is populated with the data correctly. But, upon second execution I am expecting the file size to be double, but it's the same size

Comment: ....,{"price":"0.00493171","quantity":"30.41540139","total":"0.14999994"},{"price":"0.00493000","quantity":Segmentation fault

Comment: gdb output  ->  http://paste.ee/p/9zch4

Comment: "warning: exec file is newer than core file." - *sigh*. did you intentionally make your task harder?

Comment: A quick look at the [docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) seems to suggest that you hand a FILE pointer where a function pointer (write_callback) is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is a mistake :

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, pFile);
```

CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION option expects a function pointer but you pass the file handler. Further more you never tell libcurl to use your write_data function.

You should have set both the write function AND the write data options.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pFile);
```

More details can be found there :

- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html
- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html